# Symfony bundles using the same vendor name in /src and /vendor

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I'm breaking some of my bundles into stand alone repos that I can reuse in other projects, they are all under the same vendor namespace in my /src directory, so when I pull them out and require them with composer I end up with the same vendor name space in my `/src` directory and also the `/vendor` directory.

When I try to load my app I get a `Compile Error` as it's looking for the class in the `/src` directory.

Is there anyway around this or do I need to change my vendor name?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the opcache needed to be cleared - restarting apache solved the issue.